# Add a column at the end of file with a value for certain number of rows

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a text file and I want to add a new column at the end with the value '0' for the first 2000 rows and '1' for the next 3000 rows. 
A code using awk or shell or sed will be suitable.

Comment: What did you try

Comment: I tried something like this : sed 's/$/ 0/' file. But it adds 0 too all the rows. I need 0 for specific rows and 1 for the others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

give this one-liner a try:

```
awk 'NR<2001{$(NF+1)=0;print;next}NR<5001{$(NF+1)=1}7' file
```

Comment: What does the '7' at the end do?

Comment: @Doodle same as `print`

Comment: Okay. Will try it out. Thank you!

Comment: It worked beautifully! I just added an '=' sign at <= 5001  to 'awk 'NR<2001{$(NF+1)=0;print;next}NR<=5001{$(NF+1)=1}7' file ' . Otherwise the last line is missed out.

Comment: @Doodle the line number parameters you can make them as awk variables so that you can pass them in from your other scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk '{ if (NR<=2000) print $0,0; else if (NR<=5000 ) print $0,1; }' input_filename
```

Of course you can change the delimiter if need

if you need to print also all the lines after 5000 you can use code like this:

```
 awk '{ if (NR<=2000) print $0,0; else if (NR<=5000 ) print $0,1; else print }'
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this one out.

Comment: I tried this : awk '{ if (NF<=2059) print $0,0; else if (NF>=2060 ) print $0,1; }' filename ...and it added 0 to all the rows of the last column.

Comment: what is gonna happen on line#3001?

Comment: @Kent, I did not read entirely the question. Will edit the answer

Comment: @RomeoNinov what is gonna happen on line#5001?

Comment: @Kent, this is not specified in question :)

Comment: you codes will change a 100k lines' file into 5000 line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196701/discussion-between-romeo-ninov-and-kent).

Comment: From my understanding, `not specified in question` means we keep those line untouched. but we shouldn't remove them from the file.

Comment: @kent, this is your understanding, right. My is different :)

Answer (score 0):

A short `awk`

```
awk '$0=$0(NR<2001?" 0":" 1")' file
```

This will add `0` for the first 2000 rows and `1` for the rest.

It you like to stop at `5000`

```
awk '$0=$0(NR<2001?" 0":(NR<5001?" 1":""))' file
```